# Is it possible to pass a Wix variable to SuppressOptionsUI?

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.8

I am trying to get the Options button on the `WixStandardBootstrapperApplication` to be hidden if the application has already been installed.

I was hoping to be able to pass a variable to `SuppressOptionsUI`. But it seems the value of `SuppressOptionsUI` **must** be a literal `yes` or `no`.

This was the code I was using.

```
    <!-- Don't show options button if we have an existing install -->
    <Variable Name="suppressOptions" Type="string" Value="no"/>
    <util:DirectorySearch
        After='PreviousInstallFolderSearch'
        Condition='PreviousInstallFolder'
        Path='[PreviousInstallFolder]'
        Result="exists"
        Variable="suppressOptions"/>

    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkSidebarLicense">
        <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
            ShowVersion="yes"
            LicenseUrl="http://static.my-site.com/EULA.html"
            LogoFile="Installer-Banner.bmp"
            LogoSideFile="Installer-FirstPage.bmp"
            SuppressOptionsUI="[suppressOptions]"
        />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```

So my question is: Is there another way of configuring the `WixStandardBootstrapperApplication` to allow SuppressOptionsUI to be configurable based upon a variable populated from a registry or directory search?

NB I am using the WixToolset only. No VBA or other MS tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Not today[™](https://www.google.com/search?q="rob+mensching"+"not+today")"

This is an open issue, available for the taking:  [WixVariable to SuppressOptionsUI](http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4070/).